# Update the Ref in models mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was a beginner at Mongoose, I have two models

1. Album Models
2. User Models

Both models have a `ref` that points to the correct models.

My question is how to update the reference in both AlbumModel and User models. Specifically, I want to update AlbumObjectId in the User models and UserObjectId in AlbumModel.

**1.Album Models**

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose";

const AlbumSchema = new Schema(
  {
    albumName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      unique: true,
      index: {
        unique: true,
      },
    },
    userId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: "users",
      required: true,
    },
    User:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: "users",
    }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);


const AlbumModel =
  mongoose.models.albums || mongoose.model("albums", AlbumSchema);

export default AlbumModel;
```

**2.User Models**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const UserSchema = new Schema(
  {
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      required: {
        value: true,
        message: "Enter Your First name",
      },
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
      required: {
        value: true,
        message: "Enter Your Last name",
      },
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: {
        value: true,
        message: "Enter Your Email",
      },
    },
    albumId: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "albums",
    }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const UserModel =
  mongoose.models.users || mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);

export default UserModel;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use middleware to achieve this. In your Album model you have a field called User with a reference to the "users" model. To update the reference, you can use a middleware function to handle the reference update whenever an album is updated. Something like this should work,

```js
// Import necessary modules

// ... your AlbumSchema definition ...

// Add a pre-save middleware to update the reference
AlbumSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  if (this.isModified('userId')) {
    try {
      // Fetch the User model
      const User = mongoose.model('users')

      // Update the User's albumId reference
      await User.findByIdAndUpdate(this.userId, { albumId: this._id })
      next()
    } catch (err) {
      next(err)
    }
  } else {
    next()
  }
})

// ... your AlbumModel export ...
```

In your User model, you have an albumId field with a reference to the "albums" model. You can similarly add a middleware function to handle the reference update whenever a user is updated.

```js
// Import necessary modules

// ... your UserSchema definition ...

// Add a pre-save middleware to update the reference
UserSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  if (this.isModified('albumId')) {
    try {
      // Fetch the Album model
      const Album = mongoose.model('albums')

      // Update the Album's userId reference
      await Album.findByIdAndUpdate(this.albumId, { userId: this._id })
      next()
    } catch (err) {
      next(err)
    }
  } else {
    next()
  }
})

// ... your UserModel export ...
```

I haven't tested this with your particular schema, but the idea is to give you an overview of the concept.